# Copy Active Directory User to OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I have Active directory installed on my Windows SErver. I want to copy some of Active directory User to OpenLDAP.

on my Active directory User

cn=admin,ou=resources,dc=mydomain,dc=com

I want to copy ou=resources to my another openldap server

cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=org

Anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The classic method is to use LDIFDE to export the user information from AD into a LDIF file, which you can then import into OpenLDAP. You may well need to modify the content of the file between the export and import steps to suit the different environments.

Here's some basic information on using LDIFDE to export data from AD - Example 10 is applicable: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/555636

And this is a useful guide for importing LDIFDE info into OpenLDAP: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ldif-files-to-make-changes-to-an-openldap-system

You can probably Google for more specific examples.

Also, there are third-party tools like Microsoft Identity Manager, NetIQ Identity Manager and so on, which will sync identities between directories for you. Or you could roll your own scripts if you wanted some basic automation.

Answer (score 0):

If you like clicking, you can use Apache Directory Studio.
you can get it here:

https://directory.apache.org/studio/downloads.html

It's graphical multiplatoform application. Unfortunately first you must install Java Runtime (JRE).

At first export directory content to *.ldif file, then import to openldap.
Of course you must know admin credentials for connecting to both ldaps.

Of course importing can report errors. You should update openldap scheme to maintain AD objects and his properties. Look for import errors :)